# Configurar a Visual Studio Community ,en C++ para que me acepte ingresar un valor a una variable, luego indicarla en un array como su dimensión

Tags: c++, array

estoy aprendiendo C++ y en Visual Studio Code al cual lo vincule con mingw. Realice un programa en donde el usuario le da la dimensión a un array y no tuve problema para ejecutarlo. Pero al querer hacerlo con Visual Studio Community no lo puede hacer, las sentencias o declaraciones son:

```
int nroX;
cout<< " Ingrese un valor "; cin >> nroX;

int miArreglo [nroX];
```

En esta última linea,  en `[nroX]` me da error. Me dice que `nroX` no es un valor constante. Lo solucione con new y delete, pero está la posibilidad de configurar de alguna manera a VSCommunity para que me lo acepte deforma directa como en VSCode.

Comment: ¿Será que puedes compartir bien el código completo? C++ no brinda la posibilidad de declarar arreglos de tamaño desconocido en tiempo de compilación. Si que puedes usar memoria dinámica para ello o alguna de las estructuras que te ofrece STL.

Comment: Te agradezco tu intervención para responder mi consulta. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Los arrays deben tener un tamaño definido en tiempo de compilación.

El estándar de C++ es muy claro al respecto y lo que estás haciendo infringe dicho estándar, ya que `nroX` es una variable, luego su valor solo puede conocerse en tiempo de ejecución.

El problema que tenemos aquí es que muchos compiladores se saltan ligeramente el estándar y aceptan los VLA (Variable Length Array). Pero como te digo es una característica que depende única y exclusivamente del compilador.

Los VLA son bastante peligrosos:

- El código no es portable, si intentas generar un binario usando un compilador que no soporte esta característica, o que la gestione de forma diferente, tu programa podría no compilar o comportarse distinto
- Los arrays se crean en la pila del programa. Es una región de memoria bastante limitada y, si se llena, tu programa muere. Los arrays suelen ocupar bastante espacio.
- Dado que los arrays se crean en la pila, no puedes modificar su ciclo de vida. Tienes que tener mucho cuidado con guardar o pasar referencias a dichos arrays para evitar acceder a ellos una vez han sido eliminados

Así que mi recomendación es que te ciñas un poco al estándar y uses `new` y `delete`, ya que sirven justamente para esto.

Comment: Gracias por tu consejo, lo tendré en cuenta.